# body onLoad XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest, onload

can the html document body onLoad function include an XMLHttpRequest? 
The onLoad function runs and the XMLHttpRequest is being sent.
From there it appears to be ignored; the onreadystatechange function is 
not called.
Subsequent XMLHttpRequests are processed properly. So I was wondering
about it's use in the onLoad function
Running with Firefox 47.0.

```
var ifm = "If-Modified-Since";
var ifmDate = "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";

function initPage() {
  document.getElementById("refreshratetxt").value = interval;
  refreshPage();
  timerval = setInterval("refreshPage()", interval * 1000);
}

function refreshPage() {
  sensordataGet();
}

function createXHR() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
<code removed here>
}

 function sensordataGet() {
  var sensordata = createXHR();
  sensordata.open("GET", "sensordataget.py", true); // _sensordataget
  sensordata.setRequestHeader(ifm, ifmDate);
  sensordata.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (sensordata.readyState == 4) {
      if (sensordata.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(sensordata.responseText);
        <code removed here>
      }
    }
  }
  sensordata.send();
}

<body onLoad="initPage()">
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can refer this one...**

```
<html>  
<head>  
<script>  
var request;  
function sendInfo()  
{  
var v=document.vinform.t1.value;  
var url="index.jsp?val="+v;  

if(window.XMLHttpRequest){  
request=new XMLHttpRequest();  
}  
else if(window.ActiveXObject){  
request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
}  

try  
{  
request.onreadystatechange=getInfo;  
request.open("GET",url,true);  
request.send();  
}  
catch(e)  
{  
alert("Unable to connect to server");  
}  
}  

function getInfo(){  
if(request.readyState==4){  
var val=request.responseText;  
document.getElementById('amit').innerHTML=val;  
}  
}  

</script>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <marquee><h1>This is an example of ajax</h1></marquee>  
<form name="vinform">  
<input type="text" name="t1">  
<input type="button" value="ShowTable" onClick="sendInfo()">  
</form>  

<span id="amit"> </span>  

</body>  
</html>
```

index.jsp

```
<%  
int n=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("val"));  

for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)  
out.print(i*n+"<br>");  

%>
```

Comment: This is an example, but it doesn't use body onLoad at all.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes you can have an XMLHttpRequest in the onLoad function. The long answer is the problem I saw was caused by a timing problem in the sensordataget python function.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the work you wanted:

```
    <script>
       window.onload = yourFunction(){
           /* executed when page is loaded*/
       };
    </script>
```